# Fetching data in React Native app using API

Tags: python, json, react-native, flask, django-rest-framework

I am developing an application on React Native, with this app i want to connect my chatbot developed on Python ( NLP) . How can i fetch data from my python trained model and run it on real time using React Native front end

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => console.log(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

above example shows how fetch data in react native app.
replace the URL https://reactnative.dev/movies.json with your API url.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
export default class Hook extends Component {
  state = {
    apiResponse: '',
    isLoading: false
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
   this.fetchData()
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
     this.setState({isLoading:true})
    const response = await axios("https://reactnative.dev/movies.json");
      this.setState({apiResponse:response.data,isLoading:false})

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use axios
[https://github.com/axios/axios]

you can fetch data from api simple enough